# Python: Plotting Histogram with hist() and specifying y axis

Tags: python, histogram

Hello im having trouble plotting my histogram
currently I get this image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwDXm.jpg
and I want to change the y values to

```
y = [0.125, 0.21875, 0.25, 0.1875, 0.0625, 0.1875, ...]
```

I am having trouble doing this though a
what I currently have is

```
numbins = range(32)
plt.title('Probabiliy of Heads from 32 Coin Tosses')
plt.xlabel('% heads')
plt.ylabel('relative frequency')
plt.hist(x,numbins,alpha=.2)
plt.show()
```

where x is the x values I have. I have x and y saved as an array such that

```
x = [array of numbers]
y = [array of numbers]
```

I tried

```
  plt.hist(x,y,alpha=.2)
```

but that does not work. Im not sure how I should go about changing this I tried looking online for a solution and couldnt find what I was looking for. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`plt.hist()` creates a histogram of data. You already have a histogram, so simply use `plt.plot(x, y, drawstyle='steps-mid')`.

Comment: I got this as the output when trying plt.plot(x,y,drawstyle='steps-mid') http://imgur.com/a/CHMaZ and this is not what i would be looking for, I want a histogram of my data which is why i though using hist() would work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for bar graph
Try this block of code:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(32)
y=[random.uniform(0,1) for p in range(32)]

plt.bar(x,y,align='center') # A bar chart
plt.title('Probabiliy of Heads from 32 Coin Tosses')
plt.xlabel('% heads')
plt.ylabel('Relative Frequency')
plt.show()
```